# Spring MVC : "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" when uploading a file?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file via Spring MVC, and I keep getting the HTTP 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect error. Following is my setup:

---

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>FileUploader</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FileUploader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileUploader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**FileUploader-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.fileuploader"/>
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/JSP/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

**FileUploadController.java**

```
package com.fileuploader;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/files")
public class FileUploaderController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/selectFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String selectFile()
    {
        return "selectFile";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile fileUpload)
    {
        //System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
        return "uploadSuccessful";
    }
}
```

And the two JSP view, **selectFile.jsp** and **uploadSuccessful.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Upload File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload Your File Here</h1>

    <form action="/FileUploader/files/uploadFile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Select a file to upload : <input type="file" name="file"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**uploadSuccessful.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload Successful</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload Successful</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

What could be causing this error ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess in upload file jsp , you should use Spring url for form action, it may be the problem. Since you are using Spring form taglib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the following config to my `FileUploader-servlet.xml`:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```